# INSERT Не добавляются данные в таблицу БД через форму $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, form

Не добавляются данные в таблицу БД через форму 
при отправке формы пишет:

```
echo "<p>Вы ввели не всю информацию, поэтому страница в базу не может быть добавлена.</p>";

<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_lesson.php">

<label>Ввеcти название страницы <br>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Ввеcти краткое описание страницы<br>
<input type="text" name="meta_d" id="meta_d">
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Ввеcти ключевые слова для страницы<br>
<input type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k">
</label>
</p> 
<p>
<label>Ввеcти Дату<br>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date">
</label>
</p>
</p> 
<p><label>Ввеcти  описание страницы с тегами<br>
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</label></p> 
<p><label>Ввеcти полный текст страницы с тегами<br>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</label></p>
<p>
<label>Ввеcти Автора урока<br>
<input type="text" name="autor" id="autor">
</label>
</p> 
<p> <label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Занести данные страницы в базу">
</label>
</p>
</form>
```

ВОТ КОД ОБРАБОТЧИКА

```
<?php 


include ("blocks/bd.php");

if ($title == ' ') {unset($title);}
if ($meta_d == ' ') {unset($meta_d);}
if ($meta_k == ' ') {unset($meta_k);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($date);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($description);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($text);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($autor);}
?>



<?php 

if (isset ($title) && isset ($meta_d) && isset ($meta_k) && isset ($date) && isset ($description) && isset ($text) && isset ($autor))
{
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO new (title,meta_d,meta_k,date,description,text,autor) VALUES (`$title`,`$meta_d`,`$meta_k`,`$date`,'$description`,`$text`,`$autor`)"); 
if ($result == 'true') {echo "<p>Ваша страница успешно добавлена!</p>";}
else {echo "<p>Ваша страница не добавлена!</p>";}
}
else 
{
echo "<p>Вы ввели не всю информацию, поэтому страница в базу не может быть добавлена.</p>";
}
?>
```

Подскажите что делать, уже пробовал разные варианты, которые находил в сети,
и апострофы ставил, и кавычки одинарные  ничё не помагает........(((

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Данные, переданные методом POST можно получить в php используя $_POST['имя поля'].
Например, значение поля с именем title:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
```

можно получить как $_POST['title'].
Готовый код обработчика:

```
<?php
include ("blocks/bd.php");

$title = $_POST['title'];
if($title == ' ' or empty($title)){
    echo "<p>Вы не ввели название</p>";
}
else{
    $meta_d = $_POST['meta_d'];
    if($meta_d == ' ' or empty($meta_d)){
        echo "<p>Вы не ввели краткое описание</p>";
    }
    else{
        $meta_k = $_POST['meta_k'];
        if($meta_k == ' ' or empty($meta_k)){
            echo "<p>Вы не ввели ключевые слова</p>";
        }
        else{
            $text = $_POST['text'];
            if($text == ' ' or empty($text)){
                echo "<p>Вы не ввели текст</p>";
            } 
            else{
                $date = $_POST['date'];
                $date = $_POST['description'];
                $date = $_POST['author'];
                if(mysql_query ("INSERT INTO new (title,meta_d,meta_k,date,description,text,autor) VALUES (`$title`,`$meta_d`,`$meta_k`,`$date`,`$description`,`$text`,`$autor`)")){
                    echo "<p>Ваша страница успешно добавлена!</p>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<p>Не удалось добавить страницу</p>";
                }                      
            }           
        }
    }
}
?>
```

P.S. и у Вас в SQL запросе перед $description стоит одиночная кавычка ' вместо бэктика `

Answer (score 0):

Я использую такой вариант

```html
<?php
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['param1']) && isset($_POST['param2']) && isset($_POST['param3']) && isset($_POST['param4'])) {

 $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
    $param2 = $_POST['param2'];
    $param3 = $_POST['param3'];
 $param4 = $_POST['param4'];
 
    require 'db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

 
 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO objects(param1, param2, param3, param4) VALUES('$param1', '$param2', '$param3', '$param4')");

    if ($result) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Object successfully created.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дык вы null пытаетесь добавить.

У вас данные приходят с post массивом, соответственно, ваши переменные $title, $meda_d< $meta_k сначала надо прировнять к соответствующим элементам $_POST массива.

К тому же несколько одноименных элементов могут перетереть друг друга.